# Can we get a Matrix from its inverse?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-inverse

Is there a way to get back a matrix if we know the inverse of the required matrix?

Suppose I have `Y=inv(A);`

How can I get A in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X = inv(Y)
```

If you have a matrix whose determinant is not zero,

```
Y*(Y^(-1)) = (Y^(-1))*Y = I
```

where I is the identity matrix.

Comment: It's perfectly ok.  =)

Comment: If you have the inverse of a matrix, then by definition you must be able to invert it *again*, or you wouldn't have the inverse in the first place. Specifying the non-zero determinant condition is redundant.

Comment: Yes, I know. I added this part because you might have a right-inverse or a left-inverse of a matrix. In that case you can't do the reverse operation. But I guess the 'inv' function on matlab only works for full rank matrices, so you are right.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, the inverse of the inverse of a matrix is the matrix itself

```
A = inv(inv(A))
```

Comment: It is not really _by definition_, but rather a property of an _invertible_ matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix